# what do you call a person who doesn't believe what another says anymore because that person is always lying?

Tags: single-word-requests

a person is always lying about where he is going to be or what he is going to be doing.  So, when he tells me something, I don't believe him anymore.  What is a word that describes me?

Comment: You're hearing him "cry wolf".

Comment: @HotLicks - That doesn't answer the question (which  is about the person who is on the receiving end) and I don't think it accurately  describes the person who lies either.

Comment: Maureen - Do you want an adjective or a noun?

Comment: Skeptical, dubious, doubtful...

Comment: .....twice shy.

Comment: [Can't get fooled again.](http://georgewbush-whitehouse.archives.gov/news/releases/2002/09/20020917-7.html)

Answer (score 2):

**skeptical.**

From the freedictionary.com

skep·ti·cal also scep·ti·cal  (skĕp′tĭ-kəl)
adj.
1. Marked by or given to doubt; questioning: skeptical of political promises.
2. Relating to or characteristic of skeptics or skepticism.
skep′ti·cal·ly adv.

Comment: This is a good description.  This would make me a skeptic.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are **distrustful**.

distrustful: unable or unwilling to trust; doubtful; suspicious ([Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distrustful))

> **Distrust vs. mistrust**
>
> Distrust and mistrust are roughly the same. Both refer to (1) lack of
>   trust, and (2) to regard without trust. But distrust is often based on
>   experience or reliable information, while mistrust is often a general
>   sense of unease toward someone or something. For example, you might
>   distrust the advice of someone who has given you bad tips in the past,
>   and you might mistrust advice from a stranger. This distinction is
>   only a general tendency, though, and it is not always borne out in
>   real-world usage.

([The Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/distrust-mistrust/))

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities.

**Dismissive** describes your reaction to his statements.

**Incredulous** "unwilling or unable to believe something" is a good start, but the lack of belief could be caused by any number of reasons.

**Profoundly mistrusting** would describe your mental state, although it is two words rather than one.

**Disillusioned** does not precisely state that you do not believe the person, but it is pretty well implied.